# How Ef generating Tsql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I like to know how I can improve the query generation  of EF  take an example

I have a DbSet ItemControllers

The Linq code  is :

```
ItemController.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name=="Acl")
```

// The euqilent Sql generated by sql is

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Limit1].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription], 
    [Limit1].[LongDescription] AS [LongDescription], 
    [Limit1].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName], 
    [Limit1].[ModuleItem_Id] AS [ModuleItem_Id]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent1].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription], 
        [Extent1].[LongDescription] AS [LongDescription], 
        [Extent1].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName], 
        [Extent1].[ModuleItem_Id] AS [ModuleItem_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[ItemControllers] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (([Extent1].[Name] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent1].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
    )  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'Acl'
```

please check the tsql  why EF creating such a long query , I can simply Get the result

by following query

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent1].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription], 
            [Extent1].[LongDescription] AS [LongDescription], 
            [Extent1].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName], 
            [Extent1].[ModuleItem_Id] AS [ModuleItem_Id]
            FROM [dbo].[ItemControllers] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE Name=@name  // few  code removed for clarity
```

.So my question is how I can improve the query generation of EF entity  by using linq function

Answer (score 4):

I think if you look at the query plans for the two queries (yours and the generated one) you will find very little difference. Linq is actually pretty good at generating efficient SQL, and in fact what it has added to your query will have practically zero cost.

The only thing to check about this SQL is that there is an index on the Name column.

Cheers -

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above but there is a way to control exactly what query SQL runs (if you want to do so) and it is by mapping a stored procedure (the exact query you want to run) as a FUNCTION IMPORT in Entity Framework. You then call your function import just as you did your entity class!

Of course, this is more work because you do have to write the SQL and the stored procs, but you can do it and it does indeed run your exact SQL!

By the way, the EF designer is actually really good at creating custom "_result" classes for your results. You do this as you are mapping your sproc as a function import. You can preview the return set inside the designer and click on the "create custom class" button.

I actually do most of my EF work via sprocs because I don't like all the clutter of entities AND I usually return very complex classes that are not necessarily how I physically store the data!

Give it a shot and you might like it.